# Laravel get count of column rows with condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Suppose if I have a table of

```
ID      Col1     Col2       Col3       Col4     Col5

1       Hello    ""         Hi          ""       ""
2       two      ""         Hi          here     ""
```

I want to get the count of Col(X) without including the empty column. So for record 1 I must have a count of `2` and for record 2 I have `3`

How can I do it in MySQL or in Laravel's Eloquent or Query Builder? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, is to sum the not empty fields. In MySQL it looks like:

```sql
SELECT *, SUM((Col1!='') + (Col2!='') + (Col3!='') + (Col4!='') + (Col5!='')) as NotEmptyFields 
FROM table 
GROUP BY ID;
```

In Laravel it looks like:

```php
Model::select(DB::raw('*, SUM((Col1!="") + (Col2!="") + (Col3!="") + (Col4!="") + (Col5!="")) as NotEmptyFields'))
    ->groupBy('ID')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
$data = DB::table('MyTable')->get();
```

Get all data from table using query like this in laravel. It return array of objects. So iterate your array using for each loop and check the columns or empty or not.

If any column is empty do nothing.

But if any column has a value count+1 add in your result array.

```
$result = [];

foreach($data as $object)
{
    $result[$object->id] = 0;

    foreach($object as $key => $value) 
    {        
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            if($key != 'id')
            {
                $result[$object->id] = $result[$object->id] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: can you explain your answer ?

Comment: yes sure, check my updated answer

Comment: ya. tried it but i dont understand the results given

Comment: result is like this Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
id 1 having 2 count and id 2 having 3 counts.

Comment: seems confusing.

Comment: $result is a array that holding counts or every $id

Comment: Share your code of getting data from db.

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad answer could become real slow on big datasets.

Try like this.

```
DB::table('model')
    ->select(DB::raw('
        (is_null(Col1) OR Col1 = '') +
        (is_null(Col2) OR Col2 = '') +
        (is_null(Col3) OR Col3 = '') +
        (is_null(Col4) OR Col4 = '') +
        (is_null(Col5) OR Col5 = '') 
            as NumberofNulls'
    ))
```

This should now count columns with either NULL or empty string in them

Comment: does `is_null` counts the empty strings? since my table is not nullable. when blank. it stays blank, not null

Comment: no, let me see if I can edit this

Comment: Okay will try your solution sir